# Testing plugins in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Im looking at the source code for unit testing in ServiceStack[TestHostBase.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Examples.Tests/TestHostBase.cs) - and got it running with my own project. 
How would i go around enabling my plugins when unit testing without actually starting a listener?
For examples i would like to test that my web service validates correctly, so i add the following code to Configure in TestHostBase.cs.

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(CustomerModelValidator).Assembly);
```

But when calling base.send with a Customer object which violates a validation rule no validation are done. (Note: Validation works allright when i start my webservice with a listener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Plugins can mutate any part of an AppHost (i.e. Add Routes, ContentTypes, Request/Response Filters, CatchAll Handlers, etc). They're not possible to test its integration with your services without starting a HttpListener (or ASP.NET host).

Of course if your Plugin is testable, you can unit test it in isolation, separate from your services.