# Is it possible to unit test ValidationFeature plugin in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicestack

I would like to unit test my `ValidationFeature` rulesets in my ServiceStack project however the plugin is not being initialized when creating my `appHost` object.

Here is my original code to initialize the `appHost`.

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    private void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        appHost = new BasicAppHost().Init();
        appHost.Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        var container = appHost.Container;
        container.RegisterValidators(typeof(ApplicationValidator).Assembly);
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<FakeRetailReferralRepository, IRetailReferralRepository>();
        container.RegisterAutoWired<SubmitApplicationService>();            
    }
```

I've tried moving the `Plugins.Add` line in between the `BasicAppHost` constructor and `Init()` and that didn't work either.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing plugins in ServiceStack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710434/testing-plugins-in-servicestack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation feature is validated within the Request Pipeline so would typically require a full integration test to test it, i.e. using a self-host and service client.

You can still unit test a validator, but as validation occurs before the Service is called you would need to test the validator with the Request DTO directly  instead of calling the Service, e.g:

```
using (var appHost = new BasicAppHost
{
    ConfigureAppHost = host => {
        host.Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
    },
    ConfigureContainer = c => {
        c.RegisterValidators(typeof(ApplicationValidator).Assembly);
    }
}.Init())
{
    var myValidator = appHost.TryResolve<IValidator<MyRequest>>();

    var result = myValidator.Validate(new MyRequest { ... });
    Assert.That(result.IsValid, Is.False);
    Assert.That(result.Errors.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```